# toggle between normal character / editor camera possible?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

For development is it possible to toggle between the normal character/pawn (like ThirdPersonCharacter) and the editor's flying camera?

I'm trying to start the game as normal char, eject and
fly somewhere using camera controls and then bring/possess the pawn *at that new location*
basically like "play from here" but without restarting the game?

I tried ToggleDebugCamera and it was -almost- what I was looking for
but when I un-toggle it puts me back to the previous position.

I'm guessing this is pretty basic but I can't find it documented anywhere.
Is there a easy way to do this? or would I have to add flying/disable gravity, etc to the char itself?

I really hope not because the editor controls are so smooth..unless I can use the default camera as a pawn or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch between the gameplay camera and the editor camera, you can try using the **Eject** button while in play mode:

[image: EjectButton]

You will then get control of the editor camera and you'll be able to return to the gameplay camera using the **Possess** button:

[image]

EDIT: If you want to actually teleport, the easiest way to do it is the `Teleport` debug command, after moving where you want using `ToggleDebugCamera`.

Cheers!

Comment: Yes but the problem is when you possess it sets you back to where the pawn is..I want to possess the pawn at the NEW camera location like fly over with camera and bring pwn here

Comment: I see, my bad then. To do that, you can use the `Teleport` command while `ToggleDebugCamera` is active, and the player will be teleported where the camera marker is. I just tested it on the default 3rd Person template and it works. Cheers!

Comment: Ahh that was driving me crazy for over a week..thanks alot!!